# Vba Word add table after copying table from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

The macro is written in Excel. I have copied the table to word first page from excel and then I would like to insert table into page 2 in word.But from below the set "MyRange" returning empty and table with 1 row is not creating.

```
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(str_path_folder & "\" & AdID & ".dotm")
    objWord.Visible = True
    objDoc.Activate
    AppActivate AdID & ".dotm"
    Sheets("Meta").Select
    Range("B1:E" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    objWord.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    objDoc.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
   objWord.Selection.InsertBreak.Type = wdPageBreak
   Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Content
   MyRange.collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
   ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=MyRange, NumRows:=1, _
   NumColumns:=1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior,       AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
```

Also if i use below it is replacing the already copied table in page 1:

```
objDoc.Tables.Add Range:=objDoc.Range, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=2, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the end of the document is `objDoc.Range(objDoc.Range.End - 1)`

```
objDoc.Range.PasteExcelTable 0, 0, 0

objDoc.Range(objDoc.Range.End - 1).InsertBreak 

objDoc.Tables.Add objDoc.Range(objDoc.Range.End - 1), 2, 2
```

If you record the macro in Word, you get something like this

```
Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, True
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=1,  _
    DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
```

Comment: thank you, but still its not added the new table in page 2. Can you suggest